# Wiring new light fitting

Tags: wiring, lighting

I am trying to change a light fitting but the old one has 4 terminals, L (I'm guessing means loop) E (earth) but nothing on the others. but the new one has a standard 3 terminals: Earth, live, natural. Have tried to wire it up like the others I have but this one either stays on or won't come on at all.  Here is a pic of the old light fitting

[image]

[image]

rose light fitting.
4 slots to 3 slots ??

the second picture is how it is wired now, I am stuck as to where I go from here as the new light fixture only has 3 terminals, and as you can see the old one has 4.

I have tried to put the red(live) black(neatual) and earth in there slots with the single red lefted out but the light is on can't turn off with switch.

Comment: "_either stays on or won't come on at all_" This sounds like [rose-wiring](https://flameport.com/electric/lighting_circuits/lighting_ceiling_rose_other_colours.cs4)

Comment: The pics just shows teh connectors.  It does not show us how it was wired before or how it is wired now.  Please show either whats at the other end of the plug or the labels on the pins.

Answer (score 0):

One of the four clumps of wires going into terminals won't actually be connected to the old light.  The terminal will only be there to connect the wires together.  It will probably be the one with two lives (red).  The single red is probably the one that comes back from the switch and is used to power the light through the switch.

You should use an additional terminal block, or something more modern like a Wago connector, to join the extra wires that now don't have a terminal.